# Is it possible to decorate parts of the text being entered in ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

For example, can I color all instances of the word 'red' with a span, while the text is being edited?  Of course I can use a simple regex when saving the data, but I am interested in coloring the text *while* it is being entered.  I haven't found any plugins that actively decorate the text as the user types.

I'm still exploring and am not tied to any version of ckeditor, or even ckeditor at all.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a similar problem and I didn't find any plugin either.  I am currently using the following manual approach:
I define a [CKEDITOR.style](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style) and use its applyToRange() method. I generate the [CKEDITOR.dom.range](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) by traversing the complete document via [CKEDITOR.dom.walker](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker).

For example you could use a walker to traverse the text.
The walker returns each "node", which allows to filter all html. Textnodes are type 3. In your case you may have to catch the case of adjecent textnodes (I got a little bit confused how the start and end of a text node are defined). 
If you have the start node and the end node of your text you want to mark, you can create a range from them. Use the method editor.createRange() and set the start- and end-element manually. Don't forget to set the offsets.

Depending on your style definition a span element is generated surounding the range. The range is updated to reference this span element. This is usefull if you wan't to remove the style again for example if the user changes the content.

Additionally you need a strategy when to check the text. Take a look at the [onChange](http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange) Plugin. Key related events could also prove helpfull.

Thats how far I am at the moment myself. If I hit problems or find easier solutions I will update my post. Sadly I am not able to share the code itself.
I didn't test very much yet. I still hope my current progress is helpfull to you.